# Preventing race conditions using multiple SELECT in INSERT statement

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I am writing a query in order to prevent concurrent queries to mess things up.
I'm pretty sure there's a much better way to do it, and that's why I'm here.

Basically the columns of the table look like this:

```
id      : INT(10) unsigned auto_incremented
number  : INT(6) unsigned zerofill
date    : DATETIME
```

When I insert a new row, here is how I need to set its **number** value :

- If the last inserted row's **date** is today, then **number** = last inserted row's number + 1
- If the last inserted row's **date** is yesterday or before, then **number** = 1

I thought about first select the last row's date and number, set the new number using php and then make my insert.

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `number`, `date` FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute();
$infos = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
if (date("Ymd", strtotime($infos['date'])) < date("Ymd", strtotime($date))) {
    $number = 1;
} else {
    $number = $infos['number'] + 1;
}

$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`number`, `date`) VALUES (:number, :date)");
$stmt2->execute(array(":number" => $number, ":date" => $date));

$pdo->commit();
```

Are transactions enough to prevent another thread selecting the same number and therefor trying to insert the same number I am trying to ?

Since I couldn't answer that question myself, even using our dear friend Google and SO, I thought "Can't I just have MySQL do all the work ?" and came up with this query :

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`number`, `date`)
SELECT IF(
    DATE((SELECT `date` FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1)) < CURDATE(),
    '1',
    (SELECT `number` + 1 FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1)
), NOW()
```

Is it a better way to do it ?

Should I just lock the table before doing anything ?

Am I just too dumb to see how this should be done ?

Comment: Looking up the scenario i concluded that you are  trying to insert a number in incrementing order with date, you can create a composite unique index on date and number column and can handle this  in exception catch block if two concurrent queries are going to enter same number on same day.

Comment: Yea, it was just a note. I don't think transactions rely on the other transaction states. If they did if you had 30 users load at once the 30th user would need all 29 transactions to finish first. I wouldn't `select` then `update` you are allowing time to pass between, do it all at once.

Comment: A transaction isn't enough to prevent selecting the same number, but if the key is unique, then the second insert will fail, and you can back out of the transaction, then try the whole mess again.

Answer (score 0):

This may suffice:

First, change the table.  No `id`, `date is a`DATE`, "natural" PK.

```
number INT(6) unsigned zerofill,
date   DATE,
PRIMARY KEY(date, number)
```

Then the transaction is

```
BEGIN;
($not_first, $number) = SELECT date = CURDATE(), number
                     FROM tbl
                     ORDER BY date DESC, number DESC
                     LIMIT 1
                     FOR UPDATE;  -- important
$number = $not_first ? $number+1 : 1;
INSERT INTO tbl (date, number, ...)
    VALUES
    ( CURDATE(), $number, ...);
COMMIT;
```

But there is still a bug if the `SELECT` runs just before midnight, but the `INSERT` runs just after.

So, this may avoid the bug, and avoid the transaction, since the statement should be atomic:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (date, number, ...)
    VALUES
    ( CURDATE(),
      IFNULL( ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl WHERE date = CURDATE() ),
                   1 ) AS number,
      ...  -- whatever else you are inserting into `tbl`
    );
```

Regardless of how you do it, you must check for errors -- another connection could be doing the same thing and lead to a deadlock or something.